# How do I edit the patients data of a DICOM file using LEADTOOLS

Tags: c#, leadtools-sdk

I want to insert dummy data in dicom file without reading that file using LEADTOOLS.
For ex. 
I want to insert

```
 Patient_Name = xyz etc.
```

So anybody have any idea that which LEADTOOLS method is used to insert/edit patients data in a dicom file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
dicomdataset.InsertElementAndSetValue(DicomTag.PatientName, "Namrata");

DicomElement element = ds.FindFirstElement(null, DicomTag.PatientName, false);
  if (element == null)
  {
     element = ds.InsertElement(null, false, DicomTag.PatientName, DicomVRType.PN, false, 0);
  }
```

Comment: But how do I insert the dummy value for patient name ??

Comment: dicomdataset.InsertElementAndSetValue(DicomTag.PatientName, "Namrata")

Comment: How do i insert the Pixel_data if my pixel data is in byte array format. I want to insert pixel data for multiframe dicom file.